# phonegap cross domain get undefined value

Tags: cordova, cross-domain, jsonp

here is my issue. I use jsonp to solve the cross domain issue, and it works on my local web page (the page request the remote server, not localhost). But when I deploy the page into phonegap as an android app, the error returns as:
XMLHttpRequest.status: 200
XMLHttpRequest.readyState: 4
textStatus:parsererror
XMLHttpRequest.responseText: undefined

Here is my test code:

For client side:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",  
         async: false,   
         url:url,  
         dataType: "jsonp",  
         jsonp: "callback", 
         jsonpCallback:"myresult", 
         success: function(data){
            if (data.flag == "success")
             alert("yeah");  
         },  
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.readyState);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }

});
```

For server side, I use php:

```
     $callback = $_GET["callback"];
     $a = array(
     "flag"=>"success"
     );
     $result = json_encode($a);
     echo "myresult($result)";
```

Comment: For more information: if I set url in HTML like: http://192.168.1.100/test.php and <access origin="192.168.1.100/*">, I can get the right response. While if I change the url and whitelist to  www.mydomain.com, it doesn't work. PS: my phone was connected in wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should [WhiteList](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide) your domain name.
The whitelisting rules are found in **res/xml/config.xml** (in case of android) and declared with the element `<access origin="*.yourdomain.com/*" />.`

Comment: I already set the WhiteList. I found there was an error: singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE when I press the submit button, is it related the above issue?

Comment: well, I didnt had any problems with json. I've done few jSON apps, and all works fluently. I dont have any ideas what else could be wrong. If you would share your app, then, maybe someone would be able to identify problem. Currently I'm out of ideas, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType:"json"` instead of `jsonp`.

see this example

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",  
         async: false,   
         url:url,  
         dataType: "json",  
         success: function(data){
            if (data.flag == "success")
             alert("yeah");  
            },  
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(errorThrown);
        }

});
```

Also, try `echo $result;` instead of  `echo "myresult($result)";`

Comment: in success:function(data) block, I can alert msg without data.flag=="success", but the data.flag still report error as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'flag' of null:555"